# How to get value from dictionary session

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have stored multiple values in session using dictionary like below

```
 var get_values = new Dictionary();
```

`get_values["name"] = model.Name; ;
                    get_values["address"] = model.Address;
                    get_values["phone"] = model.Phone;
                    get_values["email"] = model.Email;


                    Session["sess_values"] = get_values;`

now i want to get values from session one by one. my question is how to get values from session like name, address etc.?

Comment: Do you mean you want to loop through all the values?

Answer (score 0):

just like any normal [dictionary](https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

```
//you get your sesssion 
var sessionDictionary =Session["sess_values"] as Dictionary<string, string>;

//then get the value, example for name 
var TheName = sessionDictionary["name"];
```